# Send 2 integers with shared memory

Tags: c, windows, shared-memory

I have a comunication Server-Client ,where i send from server to client an integer with CopyMemory function .My question is if i what to send a seccond integer by the same pointer obtained by MapViewOfFile can i just call CopyMemory to the same pointer , or i must create another FileMapp, obtain MapViewOfFile etc.Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can write multiple times to the same memory -- but you'll normally need to use some sort of synchronization (e.g., an Event) to tell the client when there's new data to process (and another from the client to the server to tell it when the current data has been read). Given that you're only writing an int, a pipe will be a *lot* easier way to do the job.

Comment: I necesrily have to use a shared memory.I will try to use syncronization.Thanks